# Materialize css --select-- not working in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, materialize

I am using basic materialize css and for some reason even if I copy it straight from the materializecss.com website my select option just shows the label and nothing else is there.

**EDIT** added index.hjs page for reference of scripts.

In my index.hjs here are all my imports for the materialize css:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--Import materialize.css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/build/bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the code:

```
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
            <input
              onChange={this.updateTask.bind(this)}
              id="title"
              type="text"
            />
            <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="input-field col s12 m6">
            <input
              onChange={this.updateTask.bind(this)}
              id="description"
              type="text"
            />
            <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="input-field col s12">
            <select id="category" onChange={this.updateTask.bind(this)}>
              <option value="" disabled selected>
                Choose your category
              </option>
              <option value="delivery">Delivery</option>
              <option value="dog walking">Dog Walking</option>
              <option value="house cleaning">House Cleaning</option>
            </select>
            <label>Category</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          {/* <button
            onClick={this.submitTask.bind(this)}
            className="btn waves-effect waves-light"
            >
            Submit
            <i className="material-icons right">send</i>
          </button> */}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I think you need js file from materialize as well.

Comment: Dropdown is under "Javascript" section. [Check here](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html)

Comment: I have the jquery and js scripts already, added page in the edits, I meant select not drop down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Materialize.css overrides browser defaults to enable select tag.
To avoid this, you can use "browser-default" class in select tag.

```html
<select class="browser-default">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
      <option value="1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="3">Option 3</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the "react-materialize" package to get materialize into your react app. Once you've set it up, it lets you do select without any wonky hacks like changing your componentDidMount() or removing styling like so:

```
<Row>
  <Input type="select" value={}>
    <option value={} key={}> your option here</option>
  </Input>
<Row>
```

see https://react-materialize.github.io/#/forms for more

Answer (score 0):

This seems a bit much to have to do for a select input, but after some research I found out how to solve this.

First you need to go into the component in which you have the select input.

In that component in the `componentDidMount()` you will add the following:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.dropdown);

    $(element).ready(function() {
      $('select').material_select();
    });
  }
```

Make sure you import `ReactDOM` at the top from `react-dom`

After this you will need to make a `ref` value in your `select` like so:

```
        <select
          ref="dropdown"
          id="category"
          defaultValue="1"
          onChange={this.updateTask.bind(this)}
        >
```

Note that the ref matches from the `this.refs.dropdown`. 
Now since we are using jQuery we need to make sure it will function and in order to do so you will need to go to your `webpack.config.js` file and add the following plugin.

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery",
      "window.jQuery": "jquery",
      "Hammer": "hammerjs/hammer",
      createDayLabel: "jquery",
      createWeekdayLabel: "jquery",
      activateOption: "jquery",
      leftPosition: "jquery"
  })
]
```

Now you are all set and should be ready to go.